# AWS don't gather properly logs in non-blocking mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging

I have faced a situation when some of the logs don't gather by awslogs driver.

Awslogs driver with mode = **non-blocking** and maximum buffer size = **25mb** (I have experimented with these values by looking at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/45999). My logs' throughput even don't have rate >25mb/s, but I lose logs when payload size is >0.25MB (this isn't a concrete number, but sounds true). I don't understand why this happens. In the code I have 5 log statements: "args", "built request", "got response" and "successfully got available hotels", on the third one "got response" log payload body can be up to 1MB (but this statement is logging when payload body <0.2 MB). What shall I suppose to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Log event size : 256 KB (maximum). This quota can't be changed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html